# UIView always loads in portrait mode

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

This one has me ripping my hair out.  My iPad application is setup as follows:

In my app delegate I have this:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

in my info.plist I have:

```
Initial Interface Orientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft
```

In my first view controller that is loaded from the app delegate I have:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations.
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

In my second view controller I have:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations.
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

Finally the views in both nibs are set to landscape in Interface Builder.  The application starts in landscape mode and there is a button that when pressed assigns the second view to the first view:

```
self.view = secondView.view;
```

the problem is that even though everything is in landscape the new view is always loaded in portrait mode?  Please any help on this would be very very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This is the bit you want to change. This is what sets the allowed initial orientations. Change it to suit your needs.

It's in the summary tab of the Target's settings.

[image: Xcode 4]

Or. if you aren't using Xcode 4 yet - you can set the orientations in the Info.plist:

[image: Xcode 3]

And so you can see all the keys:

[image: Xcode 3 All keys]

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  You're screen shot is xCode 4, do you know where this is found in xCode 3?

Comment: @Peter - Have a look at the 'Supported interface orientations' key in the Info.plist.

Comment: @Peter: You should really think about upgrading to Xcode 4, Xcode 3 will become unusable for iOS5.